# What's the reason to use completely different and new post editor on moderator election page?

Tags: support, election, editor, stacks-editor

Currently the [moderator election on RuSO](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/election?cb=1) is in progress. The page for nominee introduction uses completely different editor (seems like the same as used for SO for Teams) compared with the regular QA part:

> [image: Election editor]

What's the reason to do this? Is this some kind of lightweight beta testing or what?

Looks like the entire editor is completely unusable on touchscreen devices. E.g. I can't press any tool button on my iPad.

Comment: IIRC, the stacks editor was rolled out to several tools (including the nomination and mod tools), just not main

Comment: @Zoe but what's the reason for that?

Comment: No clue. I assume it's related to it being in beta (which it really shouldn't be; it isn't remotely close to complete enough for any use, much less a beta). That said, I vaguely remember something about the old editor being replaced in new or updated tools, so it might be related to that?

Comment: That editor has been used for other elections for a while now (about 2 years). Your last election was 3 years ago, before the change. As to why, I'm sure that question has been asked before. I simply can't find it, it may have been on a site-specific meta or in chat. I think the elections had it even before Teams had it. Probably part of the test, or something.