# Unable to translate stacks-editor

Tags: bug, status-review, localization, stacks-editor, traducir

Stacks-editor used in particular [on election nominee page](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/388101/339911) is not prepared to translate. All strings from tool buttons etc are not translated and there're no strings in traducir to translate:

> [image]

Comment: The Stacks Editor [has had localization support for a while now](https://github.com/StackExchange/Stacks-Editor/issues/60); it appears they just need to hook it up to their existing localization pipeline/ Traducir.